# Problem using NDSolveValue

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

Good afternoon, fellas. Could anyone here help me solve this problem?

`umi = NDSolveValue[{kh t D[u[t, r], r] - 2 \[Pi] a u[t, r] + 2 \[Pi] a == 0, 
   u[t, 302] == 0.21}, u, {t, 0.000001, 10^6}, {r, 298, 302}, 
  MaxStepFraction -> 0.001]`

I got this:
At r == 302.`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff \
system suspected. >>

'kh' and 'a' are constants

What Am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: And what is the value of those constants? It seems to work fine if I substitute them for 1 arbitrarily.

Comment: kh = 10^-6  and  a = 300

Comment: You may try the option `SolveDelayed -> True` and take a look at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveIntroductoryTutorialDAEs.html).

Comment: Still doesn't work. Now I got this:

Comment: NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the \
differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from \
those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial \
conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is \
recommended. >>

Answer (score 4):

This can actually be solved analytically (`DSolve`), noting it is only algebraic in `t`:

```
 urt[r_, t_] = 
    Simplify[(u /. 
         First@DSolve[{kh t D[u[r], r] - 2 Pi a u[r] + 2 Pi a == 0, 
             u[302] == 21/100}, u, r])[r]]
```

> 1 - 79/100 E^((2 a Pi (-302 + r))/(kh t))

```
 Plot3D[urt[r, t] /. {kh -> 10^-6, a -> 300}, {t, 10, 200}, {r, 298, 
    302}]
```

[image]

Pretty obvious why the numerical solver has a hard time with it..

Comment: Thanks a lot, George. But I don't get why when t = 0, urt = 1. It should be u[initial] = 0.21. I mean, urt should be 0.21 at any point r when t = 0 and urt shouldn't change at r >= 302. I guess I'm not putting it well.

Comment: your condition `u[t, 302] == 0.21` says `u=.21` for *all* `t` and `r=302`.  (The analytic solution satisfies that, although it rises so sharply at the edge `Plot3D` doesn't show it very well )

Comment: I tried to put the initial condition but it didn't work. It only accepts constraints on r.

Comment: Maybe put the condition that u doesn't change for r>= 302 may work better. How do I do it? D[u[302], r] == 0 ?

Comment: Is this some physical problem?  Start there and develop boundary conditions that make sense.

Comment: Thanks, George. I got it. It a physical problem indeed.